# Get the field-index of same-name-combos (select / dropdown), added after page-load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I want to get the field-index of same-names-field i.e. '`item_id[]`'.
As I select/change an item from '`Item Name`' drop-down, its combo-field-index should be shown in '`span`' under '`Available`' against this dropdown.

Actually the purpose of getting the index of current combo is to show Available-Quantity in '`Span`' against this combo under '`Available`'.

(dropdown field is named 'item_id[]', index is started from 0, counting from upper most drop down to the current one)

Please copy/paste all code along with Javascript, use '`Add Rows`' link and force Javascript/jQuery to work for all rows (previous and `newly added elements`). Thanks.

**EDITED:**

In short, **I need to alert() the current index of item-name-combo-field after using 'Add Row' link** (onchange event). This is enough for my solution (and I will manage everything else).

**CODE I HAVE USED:**

But it works just if used for text-box not for combo AND only for elements which are loaded on page-load not for added (appended) elements using 'Add Row' link.

```
var my_field = $('select[name="item_id[]"]');
my_field.on('change', function() {
  var index = my_field.index( this );
  alert( this.value + ', ' + index );
});
```

[image]

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="41%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="contentstable">
    <tr>
      <th width="35%" align="center">Item Name </th>
      <th width="14%" align="center">Quantity </th>
      <th width="26%" align="center">item Sr. # </th>
      <th width="18%" align="center">Store Status </th>
      <th width="18%" align="center">Mode </th>
      <th width="7%" align="center">Available </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="item_id[]" id="item_id[]" class="combo" style="width:326px;" onchange="showIssuableQty(this.value);">
          <option value="0"> </option>
          <option value="1">item-1 ( Model# BN004 ) </option>
          <option value="2">item-2-check ( Model# FG-56 ) </option>
          <option value="3">Item - 3 - Piston of Crane's Engine (Hitachi) Large size heavy duty ( Model# machine2-model-3CD ) </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="quantity[]" type="number" id="quantity[]" value="" class="field_3" style="width:99px;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="item_sr_no[]" type="text" id="item_sr_no[]" value="" class="field_3" style="width:199px;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="store_status[]" class="combo" id="store_status[]" style="width:119px;">
          <option value="New" selected="">New </option>
          <option value="Repaired">Repaired </option>
          <option value="Used">Used </option>
        </select>
        <td>
          <select name="type[]" class="combo" id="type[]" style="width:119px;">
            <option value="Consume" selected="">Consume </option>
            <option value="Borrow">Borrow </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="qty_avail">Qty-Here    </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="25%" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-size:17px">
              <br>
              <span ">    <input name="add_rows " id="add_rows " type="number " value="1 " style="width:63px; " onkeypress="handle_addRows(event); "> &nbsp;     <a href="javascript: " onclick="addRows(); ">Add Rows    </a>    </span">    </td>
    <td width="55%">
    <p id="issuable_qty">Issuable Qty    </p>
    </td>
    <td width="20%" class="submittd" style="text-align:right">    <br>    <input name="save" type="submit" class="submit" id="addnewcategory" value="Save Record">    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>    </table>

 </form>
```

Javascript Used:

```
<script>
/*var textboxes = $('select[name="item_id[]"]');

    textboxes.on('change', function() {
    var index = textboxes.index( this );
    alert( this.value + ', ' + index );
    });
    alert('abc');*/

function addMoreRow() {
  var tbl_name = document.getElementById("contentstable");
  var rowCount = tbl_name.rows.length;
  var row = tbl_name.insertRow(rowCount - 1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = "    <select name=\"item_id[]\" class=\"combo\" id=\"item_id[]\" onchange=\"showIssuableQty(this.value);\" value=\"\" style=\"width:326px;\" >    <option>    </option>    <option value='1'>item-1 ( Model# BN004 )    </option>    <option value='2'>item-2-check ( Model# FG-56 )    </option>    <option value='3'>Item - 3 - Piston of Crane's Engine (Hitachi) Large size heavy duty ( Model# machine2-model-3CD )    </option>    </select>";
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell2.innerHTML = "    <input name=\"quantity[]\" type=\"number\" class=\"input\" id=\"quantity[]\" value=\"\" style=\"width:99px;\" />    <input name=\"prev_quantity[]\" type=\"hidden\" class=\"input\" id=\"prev_quantity[]\" value=\"\" style=\"width:99px;\" />";
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell3.innerHTML = "    <input name=\"item_sr_no[]\" type=\"text\" class=\"input\" id=\"item_sr_no[]\" value=\"\" style=\"width:199px;\" />";
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell4.innerHTML = "    <select name=\"store_status[]\" class=\"combo\" id=\"store_status[]\" value=\"\" style=\"width:119px;\" >    <option value='New' selected >New    </option>    <option value='Repaired'>Repaired    </option>    <option value='Used'>Used    </option>    </select>    <input name=\"prev_store_status[]\" type=\"hidden\" class=\"input\" id=\"prev_store_status[]\" value=\"\" style=\"width:119px;\" />";

  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  cell5.innerHTML = "    <select name=\"type[]\" class=\"combo\" id=\"type[]\" value=\"\" style=\"width:119px;\" >    <option value='Consume' selected >Consume    </option>    <option value='Borrow'>Borrow    </option>    </select>";

  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  cell6.innerHTML = "    <span class=\"qty_avail\">&nbsp;    </span>";

}

function addRows() {
  var add_rows = document.getElementById('add_rows');
  //alert(add_rows.value);
  for ($i = 1; $i <= add_rows.value; $i++) {
    addMoreRow();
  }
}

function handle_addRows(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Ensure it is only this code that runs
    addRows();
  }
}

var itemIds = new Array('1', '2', '3');
var itemNames = new Array('', '', '');
var newItems = new Array('2357', '452', '215');
var usedItems = new Array('12', '333', '57');
var toRepairItems = new Array('234', '65', '321');
var repairedItems = new Array('789', '3', '56');
var itemThreshold = new Array('34', '56', '67');

function showIssuableQty(item_id) { // This function is not working properly, see it later.
  document.getElementById('issuable_qty').innerHTML = 'abc';
  var item_index = itemIds.indexOf(item_id);
  var strQtyMsg = 'Issuable Qty (    <b>' + (parseInt(newItems[item_index]) + parseInt(repairedItems[item_index]) + parseInt(usedItems[item_index])) +
    '    </b> )' + '    <br />' + 'New (    <b>' + newItems[item_index] + '    </b> ), Repaired (    <b>' + repairedItems[item_index] + '    </b> ), Used (    <b>' + usedItems[item_index] + '    </b> )';

  if (parseInt(newItems[item_index]) + parseInt(repairedItems[item_index]) < parseInt(itemThreshold[item_index])) {
    //if( parseInt(newItems[item_index]) + parseInt(repairedItems[item_index])    < 100 ){
    strQtyMsg = strQtyMsg + '    <br />Qty. below threshold ( ' + itemThreshold[item_index] + ' ) ';
    strQtyMsg = strQtyMsg + '    <a href="../module_request/new_request.php">Request Items    </a>    ';
    alert('Qty. is below threshold! Please generate a request to purchase.');
  }
  document.getElementById('issuable_qty').innerHTML = strQtyMsg;
  //alert(item_index);
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson - Please solve my problem, thanks

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried, what happened when you tried it, what the expected result should be (clearly) and where (more specifically) you are stuck. in it's current form, this question is more: "I have this, now I want this, do it for me". Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will help you to get more help. SO is _not_ a free coding service where you just make an order and we'll do it for you.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson - You up till didn't helped me even a bit and saying me to learn to ask a question where as you already have edited your comment 3 times. Anyway I will try to learn to ask in more manners next time.

Comment: Dear experts! I have added the code which I have already tried and the outcomes, If you do not mind, you can please look into it, thanks.

Comment: Dude ... whoa ... First of all, you're using the jQuery Lib, yet you're not ... I mean seriously, do you want Vanilla or jQuery? I can tell you, part of the reason no one is answering is because you're code is ... well ... OK, it's not the worst I've seen, but can be much improved. I suggest you reread through your code and decide which direction you're going first: Vanilla or jQuery? After that, I suggest rereading it again and changing certain things to fit your direction. Example, if you choose jQuery, then learn about [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Also, please use an IDE with good Code Tabifying/Indentations. It makes it much easier for others to read. Although I just copy and pasted it to [jsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/), it will help you a lot to have code you can read more easily. If money is an issue, [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) is a free version of their IDE and is pretty much just like the pay for version, except you have to do all the settings and such manually. However, if money is tight and you're new to coding, I'd strongly recommend it. Your code will look MUCH cleaner written in that.

Comment: Idk, I guess upon second inspection, it's not that badly indented. It just uses 2 spaces, which I personally don't like, but you also have some jumbled up HTML that was a bit of a pain to read through at first. I would still suggest you make sure you're writing code in something that can handle full HTML/JS intellisense. Anyway, just a few suggestions. I'll look over this later and maybe come back with an answer. Till then, I also still strongly suggest a rewrite to your JS. Choose a side (hint: i'd choose jQuery! it's super ez!)

Comment: Oh && 1 last suggestion. Before you edit your Question again or ask any more, you should really take the time to read this: [How Do I Make A Stack Snippet?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) && this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @SpYk3HH - Thanks for so much instructions, :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code could be much shorter.

1. you should only have one item per id, so I have changed the id names
   in your html to classes.
2. for the select in your first bit of code you can move the selector
   to become an argument of the function, this means the new `change`
   selectors will be recognised after the dom has been updated.
3. your first table row making function has been removed and replaced
   by simply copying the html into a variable and using that to
   duplicate new rows.
4. your last function contents have been changed to numbers to
   eliminate all of the string parsing and simplify

here's a working fiddle.

```js
$('body').on('change', 'select.combo', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var index = $this.parent().parent('tr').index();
  alert($this.val() + ', ' + index);
});

var rowTemplate = $('#contentstable tr').eq(1).html(); // make a copy of the standard row html content as defined in the html
rowTemplate = '<tr>' + rowTemplate + '</tr>';

function addRows() {
  var add_rows = parseFloat($('input#add_rows').val());
  for (var i, i = 1; i <= add_rows; i++) {
    $('#panel').before(rowTemplate); // insert the standard row above the addrow area
  }
}

function handle_addRows(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Ensure it is only this code that runs
    addRows();
  }
}


var itemIds = [1, 2, 3];
var itemNames = ['', 0, 0, 0];
var newItems = ['', 2357, 452, 215];
var usedItems = ['', 12, 333, 57];
var toRepairItems = ['', 234, 65, 321];
var repairedItems = ['', 789, 3, 56];
var itemThreshold = ['', 34, 56, 67];

function showIssuableQty(item_id) { // This function is not working properly, see it later.
  //  $('#issuable_qty').html('abc');
  var item_index = parseFloat(item_id); // parseInt(itemIds.indexOf(item_id));
  var newAndRepaired = newItems[item_index] + repairedItems[item_index];
  var strQtyMsg = 'Issuable Qty (    <b>' + (newAndRepaired + usedItems[item_index]) +
    '    </b> )' + '    <br />' + 'New (    <b>' + newItems[item_index] + '    </b> ), Repaired (    <b>' + repairedItems[item_index] + '    </b> ), Used (    <b>' + usedItems[item_index] + '    </b> )';

  if (newAndRepaired < itemThreshold[item_index]) {
    //if( parseInt(newItems[item_index]) + parseInt(repairedItems[item_index])    < 100 ){
    strQtyMsg = strQtyMsg + '    <br />Qty. below threshold ( ' + itemThreshold[item_index] + ' ) ';
    strQtyMsg = strQtyMsg + '    <a href="../module_request/new_request.php">Request Items    </a>    ';
    alert('Qty. is below threshold! Please generate a request to purchase.');
  }

  if (item_index === 0) {
    strQtyMsg = 'Issuable Qty (   </b> )';
  }
  $('#issuable_qty').html(strQtyMsg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="41%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="contentstable">
    <tr>
      <th width="35%" align="center">Item Name</th>
      <th width="14%" align="center">Quantity</th>
      <th width="26%" align="center">item Sr. #</th>
      <th width="18%" align="center">Store Status</th>
      <th width="18%" align="center">Mode</th>
      <th width="7%" align="center">Available</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="item_id[]" id="" class="item_id[] combo" style="width:326px;" onchange="showIssuableQty(this.value);">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="1">item-1 ( Model# BN004 )</option>
          <option value="2">item-2-check ( Model# FG-56 )</option>
          <option value="3">Item - 3 - Piston of Crane's Engine (Hitachi) Large size heavy duty ( Model# machine2-model-3CD )</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="quantity[]" type="number" id="" value="" class="quantity[] field_3" style="width:99px;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="item_sr_no[]" type="text" id="" value="" class="item_sr_no[] field_3" style="width:199px;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="store_status[]" class="combo store_status[]" id="" style="width:119px;">
          <option value="New" selected="">New</option>
          <option value="Repaired">Repaired</option>
          <option value="Used">Used</option>
        </select>
        <td>
          <select name="type[]" class="type[] combo" id="" style="width:119px;">
            <option value="Consume" selected="">Consume</option>
            <option value="Borrow">Borrow</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="qty_avail">Qty-Here    </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='panel'>
      <td colspan="6">
        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="25%" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-size:17px">
              <br>
              <span>    <input name="add_rows" id="add_rows" type="number" value="1" style="width:63px; " onkeypress="handle_addRows(event); "> &nbsp;     <a href="javascript: " onclick="addRows(); ">Add Rows    </a>    </span> 
            </td>
            <td width="55%">
              <p id="issuable_qty">Issuable Qty</p>
            </td>
            <td width="20%" class="submittd" style="text-align:right">
              <br>
              <input name="save" type="submit" class="submit" id="addnewcategory" value="Save Record">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Sam very very very much. You in fact, got the logic of the post & guided me like a friend. Actually I am a beginner in jQuery and stuck in a php-project which needed this logic. Thanks again a lot :-)